# Graph SDK doesn't always return a list of subscriptions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

The following code does not throw exceptions.   However, on occasion I have to run it a few times in a row for it to return a list of subscriptions I know are there.

- This is running as a confidential client.
- I am subscribing to Calendar Events

  ```
   static async Task<GraphServiceSubscriptionsCollectionPage> ListSubscriptions(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
   {
       GraphServiceSubscriptionsCollectionPage subscriptions = null;
       try
       {
           subscriptions = (GraphServiceSubscriptionsCollectionPage)await graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().GetAsync();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);

       }
       return subscriptions;

   }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15648) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/708599/get-subscription-api-is-not-working.html) it looks like that subscriptions are internally stored in CosmosDB and the endpoint `GET /subscriptions` has some issue with getting correct results from CosmosDB.

Even if the first page doesn't return any data check the `NextPageRequest` and make request to get next page.

```
var subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
try
{
    var subscription = await client.Subscriptions.Request().GetAsync();
    subscriptions.AddRange(subscription.CurrentPage);

    while (subscription.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        subscription = await subscription.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        subscriptions.AddRange(subscription.CurrentPage);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Very useful info.  I'll add that to my code ASAP!!

Comment: It worked!   The first few entries in the while loop didn't produce anything, but as long as NextPage was not null, I kept going ... then WHAMO!  There was the data!!!!

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I found that there already is a mechanism to page through the collection of items returned by Graph API

[Page through a collection using the Microsoft Graph SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp)

```
                var subscriptions = await ListSubscriptions(graphClient);

            int count = 0;
            int pauseAfter = 3;
            var pageIterator = PageIterator<Subscription>
                .CreatePageIterator(
                  graphClient,
                  subscriptions,
                  (s) =>
                  {
                      sb.Clear();
                      sb.AppendLine("     Change Type: " + s.ChangeType);
                      sb.AppendLine("      Expiration: " + s.ExpirationDateTime.ToString());
                      sb.AppendLine("        Resource: " + s.Resource);
                      sb.AppendLine("Notification Url: " + s.NotificationUrl);
                      sb.AppendLine(" Subscription Id: " + s.Id);
                      sb.AppendLine("-------------------------------------------------------");

                      Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                      count++;
                      // If we've iterated over the limit,
                      // stop the iteration by returning false
                      return count < pauseAfter;
                  });

            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

            while (pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Iteration paused for 5 seconds...");
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                // Reset count
                count = 0;
                await pageIterator.ResumeAsync();
            }
```